# OpenTelemetry Export to Elastic Search without Elastic APM

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, open-telemetry

I'd like to export trace/metrics data to Elastic Search using OpenTelemetry, but I'd prefer to avoid Elastic APM. Is it possible?
The opentelemetry contrib [repo](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/elasticexporter#sample-configuration-using-an-elastic-api-key) apparently suggests it is possible, however, I did not find anything on elastic.co documentation. By the way, openapm.io implies [see here](https://openapm.io/landscape?instrumentation-lib=opentelemetry&agent=elastic-beats&storage=elasticsearch&showCommercial=true&showFormats=false), OpenTelemetry can export to elastic beats (which is extremely desirable), but again, I did not find anything in Elastic.co docs.

Comment: I don't think you will find anything to this particular case in the Elastic documentation as it expects that you will use Elastic APM. To use filbeat you would need to export to a local file, using udp/tcp or using kafka, then beats would send data to elasticsearch. I do not use opentelemetry, but there is this [elasticsearch exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/elasticsearchexporter#elasticsearch-exporter) in their github.

Comment: Thanks, the plugin you mentioned only sends logs to elastic search. We'd like to send trace/metrics data too. Elastic APM server seems a bit bloated. A plugin for export on edge machine or the elastic should do the job.

Comment: If you can export the traces and metric data to a file or at least to kafka, then you can use filebeat to send it to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Traces & metrics are meant for near real-time usage. The best I've found is to configure Open Telemetry Collector to send metrics to a Metricbeat module configured to receive Prometheus metric data. There is no such thing as a Jaeger trace beat for traces.

Comment: I've added an answer how to implement this using OpenTelemetry exporter. It is a bit long answer but it works, really well.

Comment: Meanwhile Elastic has added some documentation about the topic: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/open-telemetry.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying this for some time, I've finally made it to work with the latest version of opentelemetry-collector-contrib (0.60.0 at the time of this writting).

First I've created a multi-node cluster with Docker Compose using the steps here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/docker.html#docker-compose-file. I also had to follow [the instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/docker.html#_set_vm_max_map_count_to_at_least_262144) to set the vm.max_map_count to at least 262144.

Then, using the same net, I started an opentelemetry-collector-contrib docker image using a command like:

```
docker run --net certs_default --name opentelemetry-collector -v C:\docker\elastic\otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml -p 4317:4317 -p 4318:4318 otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.60.0
```

The configuration file is very simple:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

  elasticsearch/trace:
    endpoints: [https://es01:9200]
    user: elastic
    password: 
    api_key: 
    tls:
      insecure_skip_verify: true

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [elasticsearch/trace]
```

Finally, I've just configured my application to use the OtlpExporter:

```
.AddOtlpExporter(configure =>
{
    configure.Protocol = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
})
```

Doing these steps, I can see my traces in Kibana. Now it would be nice to have some template to display a single trace with all the spans.

Answer (score 2):

When this question was asked OpenTelemetry standard and implementation was still quite young. Even as I write this answer some things are not quite fully implemented or settled yet but the **TLDR; Yes, its possible, it works and its epic!**

(original class was refactored - just browse the repo for example - its also a really good good package)

[A good reference I go back to quite often can be found here](https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless.Net/tree/main/src/Exceptionless)

You need to understand there are three key things in Observability paradigm. Trace, Logs and Metrics. All these are separate, work and implemented separately.

The key findings that I have learnt so far to configure this in .NET Framework and AspNetCore are the same apart from how you configure it.

Trace and Metrics work with SDK Builders and Logging uses the ILoggerProvider pattern

> These examples use the non DI methods for manual configuration. You
> can use `Contrib.Hosting` and read the guides there for DI approach.

**Trace**

```
System.Diagnostics.Activity.DefaultIdFormat = System.Diagnostics.ActivityIdFormat.W3C;
```

That is required in NetFramework apps in your global in NetCore that is default

```
var traceProviderBuilder = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder();
```

Gets your builder setup

```
traceProviderBuilder
    .AddSource("*")
    .SetResourceBuilder(
        ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
            .AddService(ResourceNameHelper.ServiceName)
            .AddAttributes(otelAttributes)
            .AddTelemetrySdk());
```

There's a few things happening here

- AddSource("*") subsribes the SDK to ALL Events (System.Diagnostics) - I use this for ease of use
- SetResourceBuilder is used to set the name of your service so that Elastics can group these
- OtelAttributes is a KeyValue collection that has `new KeyValuePair<string, object>("deployment.environment", environmentName)` in it so you can get the Environment drop down working in Elastics

That is the core configuration required so you can subscribe to your own Traces but you want to add Instrumentation afterwards like

- `AddAspNetInstrumentation(options => { options.RecordException = true; })`
- `.AddHttpClientInstrumentation((httpConfig) => { httpConfig.RecordException = true; })`
- `AddSqlClientInstrumentation((sqlConfig) => { sqlConfig.EnableConnectionLevelAttributes = true; sqlConfig.SetDbStatement = true; })`
- `.AddAWSInstrumentation()`

Now comes the import part, the OtlpExporter

`traceProviderBuilder.AddOtlpExporter(options)`

passing in your options

```
otlpExporter.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
otlpExporter.Endpoint = new Uri(otlpEndpoint);
otlpExporter.Headers = otlpHeaders;
```

The header is bearer token that you need from Kibana.

And finally you build it

`.Build()`

When manually configuring like this you need to manage the disposal of the SDK. That is why using DI is recommended.

Phew.. That is quite some configuration going on there. But once you get that running in the most basic form you will start to see Traces appear in the Observability part of Elastics. The first time you do this you need to give Elastics some time to sort out its indexing and trace streams (in the cloud version all that is done automagically given you have the NEW version of APM enabled in Fleet - Theres no mention of OpenTelemtry configuration on that page. just copy and paste the URLs and keys it gives you)

**Metrics**

The same applies for Metrics basically.. you have to do it all again but using

`_meterProvider = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder().AddRuntimeMetrics()`

And then all the instrumentation and OtlpExporter options.

In Framework the Metrics are quite limited abotu runtime metrics but in AspNetCore they are decent.

**Logging**

This is quite easy to implement following the Dotnet OpenTelemetry documentation but as of today is a bit buggy (Hopefully it will be stable in version 1.3)

---

I am sorry about long post but I hope this helps people a bit since I my self struggled with little or no documentation for this on Elastics, OpenTelemetry or the Dotnet Github pages.

Comment: Your reference link at the beginning leads to a 404 page now

Comment: Pfff thanks. Looks like the repo owner did quite a massive refactor. I'll just leave the link to the repo in.. people can a browse. Thanks